# How to disable a resource in google_compute_instance with Terraform

Tags: google-compute-engine, terraform

I want to create an instance and depending on some variable create an attached disk .

```
...
variable "extra-disk-count" {
    default = "0"
}

variable "extra-disk-size" {
    default = "100"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "openqa" {
    count        = "${var.count}"
    name         = "${var.name}-${element(random_id.service.*.hex, count.index)}"
    machine_type = "${var.type}"
    zone         = "${var.region}"

    boot_disk {
        initialize_params {
            image = "${var.image_id}"
        }
    }

    attached_disk {
        source      = "${element(google_compute_disk.default.*.self_link, count.index)}"
        device_name = "${element(google_compute_disk.default.*.name, count.index)}"
    }
    ....
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "default" {
  name  = "ssd-disk"
  count = "${var.extra-disk-count}"
  type  = "pd-ssd"
  zone  = "${var.region}"
  size  = "${var.extra-disk-size}"
  physical_block_size_bytes = 4096
}
```

I can set `var.extra-disk-count = 0` if I don't want to create the disk, but then I get the error

```
* google_compute_instance.openqa: element: element() may not be used with an empty list in:

${element(google_compute_disk.default.*.self_link, count.index)}
```

cause it tries to add an element that is not created.

How to "disable" the `attached_disk` option in `google_compute_instance` when `var.extra-disk-count = 0` ?

Comment: Which version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: Terraform v0.11.13

Comment: But if that's not possible with 0.11 I can try to upgrade to 0.12 if there is an easier way.

Comment: It's possible in pre 0.12 (depending on whether you rely on the output of the `google_compute_instance.openqa` resource) but easier with 0.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "google_compute_attached_disk" instead of attached_disk in google_compute_instance.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_attached_disk.html

```
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "default" {
  count = "${var.extra-disk-count}"
  disk = "${element(google_compute_disk.openqa.*.self_link, count.index)}"
  instance = "${element(google_compute_instance.default.*.self_link, count.index)}"
}
```

Note that extra-disk-count should be 0 or same with  number of google_compute_attached_disk.default (var.count). if extra-disk-count is more then var.count, it makes error. And if extra-disk-count is more then 0 and less then var.count, some compute instances will not have disks.

So I want to modify like below,

```
// remove extra-disk-count

variable "create-extra-disk" {
  default = "false"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "openqa" {
  count        = "${var.count}"
  name         = "${var.name}-${element(random_id.service.*.hex, count.index)}"
  machine_type = "${var.type}"
  zone         = "${var.region}"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "${var.image_id}"
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "default" {
  count    =  "${var.create-extra-disk ? var.count: 0}"
  disk     = "${element(google_compute_disk.openqa.*.self_link, count.index)}"
  instance = "${element(google_compute_instance.default.*.self_link, count.index)}"
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "default" {
  name                      = "ssd-disk"
  count                     = "${var.create-extra-disk ? var.count : 0}"
  type                      = "pd-ssd"
  zone                      = "${var.region}"
  size                      = "${var.extra-disk-size}"
  physical_block_size_bytes = 4096
}
```

if create-extra-disk is false, no extra disk will be created and attached.
if create-extra-disk is true, extra disk will be created and attached to all of compute instances.

Comment: That worked perfect. Thanks a lot!
Just a small correction. The last resource should be "google_compute_disk"

Comment: Good. I modified as your comment